# Prolog check if list contains even number of an element

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, tail, head

I have to check if a list contains an even number of an element without built-ins.

Example:

```
containsEvenNumber([a,b,c,a,a], a).
```

**returns false**

```
containsEvenNumber([a,b,c,a], a).
```

**returns true**

Current state:

```
not(A) :-
    A, !,
    fail.
not(_).
equal([E|_], E).
containsEvenNumber([], _).
containsEvenNumber([E|Tail], E) :-
    unevenCount(Tail, E).

containsEvenNumber([Head|Tail], E) :-
    not(equal([Head|Tail], E)),
    evenCount(Tail, E).

evenCount([], _).
evenCount([E|Tail], E) :-
    unevenCount(Tail, E).

evenCount([Head, Tail], E) :-
    not(equal([Head|Tail], E)),
    unevenCount(Tail, E).

unevenCount([], _) :-
    fail.
unevenCount([E, Tail], E) :-
    evenCount(Tail, E).

unevenCount([Head, Tail], E) :-
    not(equal([Head|Tail], E)),
    unevenCount(Tail, E).
```

I try to switch between states upon the occurrence of the element.
It doesn't work because I never go into the state, where the head is not the element or rather said, I also go into the state and return false when the head is the element.

How can I make it work/fix it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible in Prolog. Without built-ins? Since all of Prolog's fundamental capabilities are "built-in", I would say not. What have you tried so far? Do you have a more specific question? Have you looked at the Prolog documentation and examined its set of operators?

Comment: Yes I should programm the following predicate: `containsEvenNumberOfTheElement(L,E).`  without any built-ins. L is a list.

Comment: That one is possible, too. You need to show what you've tried and ask a specific question.

Comment: I edited this one now, I hope you can help me :)

Comment: The "switching between states" is actually a good way to solve this problem, but you have several issues: (1) You don't need to define `not/1`. It's already defined in SWI Prolog, and ISO prolog has `\+` (that's not a bug, but just a comment); (2) `[Head, Tail]` should be `[Head | Tail]` and `[E, Tail]` should be `[E|Tail]`; (3) your base case for `unevenCount/2` (I assume you really mean `oddCount`?) is incorrect. It should be `unevenCount([X], X).` Using a failing clause as a base case will cause your predicate to fail.

Comment: Predicates in Prolog do not _return_ true or false, they _succeed_ or _fail_. Using the appropriate terminology helps you keep the actual behavior straight and not fall into erroneous patterns of thought!

Comment: I just updated it with his suggestions and updated my approach (which is probably not possible, I guess)

Comment: @lurker I rolled it back, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "switching between states" is actually a good way to solve this problem. The logic should follow these simple rules:

> 1. There are an even number of `X` elements in `[X|Xs]` if there are an odd number of `X` elements in `Xs`.
> 2. There are an even number of `X` elements in `[Y|Xs]` if `X` and `Y` are different, and there are an even number of `X` elements in `Xs`.
> 3. There are an odd number of `X` elements in `[X|Xs]` if there are an even number of `X` elements in `Xs`.
> 4. There are an odd  number of `X` elements in `[Y|Xs]` if `X` and `Y` are different, and there are an odd number of `X` elements in `Xs`.

Then you have the base cases:

> There are an even number of any element in `[]`.
>
> There are an odd number of `X` in `[X]`.

You just need to write these rules as Prolog. However, your implementation has a few issues.

In a few cases, you are writing a list as `[Head, Tail]` instead of `[Head|Tail]`. `[Head, Tail]` is a list of exactly two elements. Also, your base case for `unevenCount/2` (which I assume you mean odd count) is incorrect. If you have a base case that always fails, then your predicate will always fail. With few exceptions, you should write your predicate clauses to succeed, not fail. Failure will occur automatically when success cannot be achieved.

Let's try to write out the rules above. ISO Prologs already have `\+`, so you do not need to define `not/1`. Also, writing `equal([E|_], E).` is unnecessary. You can do this directly in your code with simplicity.

```
evenCount(_, []).          % base case for even
evenCount(X, [X|Xs]) :-    % rule #1
    oddCount(X, Xs).
evenCount(X, [Y|Xs]) :-    % rule #2
    dif(X, Y),
    evenCount(X, Xs).

oddCount(X, [X]).          % base case for odd
oddCount(X, [X|Xs]) :-     % rule #3
    evenCount(X, Xs).
oddCount(X, [Y|Xs]) :-     % rule #4
    dif(X, Y),
    oddCount(X, Xs).
```

SWI Prolog defines `dif/2`. You could also use `\==` but it's not purely defined (and so doesn't behave as generally) as `dif/2`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have some concerns though. I think this approach will also fail, upon entering two predicates at the same time (If I speak correctly). As an example : `evenCount(1, [1|2,3])` will enter `evenCount(X, [X|Xs])` and `evenCount(X, [Y|Xs])` and the second one will fail at `dif(1,1)`. Also I guess `dif` is a built-in and therefore not suitable unfortunately. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @beefsausage You should try the code I provided to validate your concerns. `evenCount(1, [1,2,3])` (which is the same as `evenCount(1, [1|[2,3]]))` will call `oddCount(1, [2,3])` and then ultimately fail as it should since 1 is not evenly included in `[1,2,3]`. And, yes, the `evenCount(X, [Y|Xs])` clause also fails since `dif(1,1)` fails, also as desired. Note that when you have multiple predicate clauses, you only need one to succeed for the query to succeed. They have an "OR" relationship with one another.

Comment: As far as built-ins are concerned, I had already mentioned you can use \== in place of `dif/2`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, but it took me a moment to get the idea! You are great, I appreciate your explanation and solution so much! You saved my day :)

Comment: @beefsausage no worries. I hope it was clear. If you have any questions about it, let me know. I suggest to all Prolog beginners: forget everything you think you know about programming. Prolog doesn't work like other languages, which are mostly imperative. Think of it as defining a set of rules: "such and such is true if this is true and that is true, etc." The idea is to define the rules to be accurate, complete, and non-overlapping (to avoid duplicate solutions).